# Handle data from ViewModel in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm using a ViewModel to pass the data from two tables to the view. One table contains name of the staff and the second table contains data like number of hours they work per week. When I list the names from one table I also want to show the working hours that match that persons ID. Is it possible to use LINQ like `where` or `equal` to make this possible? Could someone show me a simple sample?

EDIT: Are there better ways to do this? Should I handle this in the Controller instead?

This is the code I'm using so far in the View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.resourceList)
{
<p>@item.FirstName</p>
}

@foreach (var item in Model.activityList)
{
<p>@item.NumberOfHoursPerWeek</p>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looping through this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.resourceList)
{
    ...
}
```

Then within that loop you can match any element in `Model.activityList` just like any other LINQ query.  Perhaps something like this?:

```
@Model.activityList.Single(a => a.SomeID == item.SomeID).NumberOfHoursPerWeek
```

The actual comparison (in this example, `a.SomeID == item.SomeID`) is up to you, as is the logic for the records you want to find (`.Where()`, `.Single()`, `.First()`, etc. depending on the behavior you expect) is up to you.  But finding an element in a collection is the same in this view code as it would be in any server-side code.

Comment: OK, thanks for the example! But I just wonder if this is a bad way to do it? I have never done a task before where I need this functionality. Is it OK to do this in View?

Comment: @3D-kreativ: Why would this be a bad way to do it?  I suppose you *could* loop through the collection *manually* and find the record you want, but there's no reason not to use LINQ syntax to accomplish that in a single expressive line of code.

Comment: I don't mean that your code example is bad!! I just wonder if this is something that should be done in the Controller or if it's a common practise to do it in the View! Just want to learn it the right way! :)

Comment: @3D-kreativ: Well, in the controller you can certainly transform the data and re-shape it to match the needs of the view.  In that case you'd likely create a view model which more accurately maps to the structure of the view and then in the controller you'd populate that view model from the backing data.  Either approach is fine, really.  It's up to you and what you find simpler and easier to support in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring all design issues, here is a solution:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.resourceList)
{
    @{
        var numberOfHours = Model.activityList.First(_ => _.UserID == item.ID).NumberOfHoursPerWeek;
    }
    <p>@item.FirstName</p>
    <p>@numberOfHours</p>
}
```

However, the View should usually be kept as simple as possible. The ViewModel is responsible for preparing the data for the View in an easily consumable form. If done right, you should not need any linq queries in your Views.

Answer (score -1):

you can use it like this

with if

```
//just an example to make condition true not displaying the exact Property or condition
@if (true)
{
    Model.Where(model=>model.UserID==User.UserID)
}
```

or with loop

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.resourceList)
 {
     //just an example not displaying the exact Property
     Model.Where(model=>model.UserID==User.UserID)
 }
```

Comment: edited the code i just write it to make the condition true

Comment: What exactly is the *purpose* of that condition, though?  Also, I suspect calling `.Where()` on `Model` is going to be an error.  The code in the question strongly implies that `Model` is not a collection type.

Comment: how you can say that where it is mentioned

Comment: Where *what* is "mentioned" exactly?  It's not clear what you're asking in that comment.

Comment: what do you mean by this What exactly is the purpose of that condition, though? Also, I suspect calling .Where() on Model is going to be an error. The code in the question strongly implies that Model is not a collection type.

Comment: Well, I'm asking why you have a condition for `if (true)`.  That will, by definition, *always be true*.  So why have it in the first place?  In the second part, I mean that the `Model` in the question *very likely* isn't a collection.  And `.Where()` is an extension method used on collection types.  Calling `.Where()` on something which doesn't define it as an extension method would result in an error.  (For example, create a simple class in your own code and try to invoke `.Where()` on an instance of that class.  Observe the error.  Semantically it doesn't even make sense to try it.)

Comment: if (true) this one was only for example not to just implement the exact code. and same for where if someone know the LINQ he will get enough idea from it and help me resolve his issue